# Including NULL only once in count

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I include NULL in the overall count?

For e.g. in the following query, I expect the count to be 2 instead of only 1 ('abc' and NULL)

```
mysql> create table test.todel (name varchar(100));

mysql> insert into test.todel values ('abc');

mysql> insert into test.todel values ('abc');

mysql> insert into test.todel values (null);

mysql> select count(distinct(name)) from test.todel;
+-----------------------+
| count(distinct(name)) |
+-----------------------+
|                     1 |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

Update:

The problem with the answers is that it will return 1 even if all the values are NULL.

```
drop table test.todel;

create table test.todel (name varchar(100));

insert into test.todel values (null);

insert into test.todel values (null);

insert into test.todel values (null);
```

In such cases, I need to return 0 and if there is any non-null value then the count should be distinct of non-null + 1 if null exist.

Comment: Why do you need the new logic? Needing to do this makes me wonder if you're trying to choose around an underlying problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace it with another value.

```
select count(distinct(coalesce(name, 1))) from test.todel;
```

The COALESCE() function returns the first of its arguments that isn't NULL.

EDIT after updated question:

You can simply do it like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM test.todel) subquery_alias
```

Comment: @shantanuo Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you count the row with the `null` value then you can get like this :

```
select count(distinct(ifnull(name, 1))) from test.todel;
```

Because `count` function not count the `null` columns

Answer (score 1):

You can use the null coalesce function, which will take the value of first argument that's not null:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(COALESCE(name, 1))) FROM test.todel;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use another way to count:

```
SELECT count(distinct(*)) FROM test.todel WHERE name IN (....)
```

Of course WHERE IN is not very fast, so you might consider HAVING or similar.